# How to modify mapping for already mapped entities in other assemblies?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'd like to custom mapping for entities in EF

For example, I have an entity:

```
public class User
{  
    public int UserId { get;set;}
    public string Firstname { get;set;}
    public string ColA {get; set;}
    public string ColB {get; set;}
}
```

It's already added mapping in OnModelCreating() in EF in common use. If i have 2 functions in 2 seperate assemblies, call AssemblyA.dll and AssemblyB.dll and they are dynamically loaded by MEF framework.

AssemblyA.dll just needs ColA and has to remove ColB and vice versa for AssemblyB.dll, so i need to define 2 new mapping classes for these 2 services and it will dynamically run to remove column according to its assembly (AssemblyA will Ignore ColB, and AssemblyB ignore ColA). I don't want to modify code of current EF because it's already in production. All changes for each assembly should be in its own.

Do EF support us to do like this ? Or could you give me a direction.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean by _mapping_. Can you include your `OnModelCreating()` code?

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what you are trying to do but:

- Every EF context can have each table and entity mapped only once
- It means if you load configuration for AssemblyA you cannot use configuration for AssemblyB
- It also means you cannot use default way how EF mapping is constructed inside `OnModelCreating` because that method is normally called only once for whole application lifetime.
- You can manually construct two `DbModel` insnaces, compile them to `DbCompiledModel` and pass them to `DbContext` constructor - that should allow you to have two different mapping configuration for AssemblyA and AssemblyB but you will never have both of them in the same context instance.
- EF migrations will most probably don't work because they expect single mapping set per database

Anyway if you are using MEF and modular architecture each entity should be either core (not related to any particular module and shared as is among modules) or module (not used by any other modules or core).

Comment: Thanks Ladislav, could you give me more about the item 3 (you told to use DbCompileModel) ? Besides, is there any ways to implement my ideas above ?